# MATLAB: Fitting parameters when input is a function

Tags: matlab, optimization, parameters, fminsearch

So sorry to ask this naive question, but I really get stuck as an absolute MATLAB newbie.

Below is what I am trying to do. I have a model that takes coin flip outcomes as its input:

```
function randomness = benHMMN(flips,rep,prior) % defined later
flips = csvread('flips.csv')
```

On the right-hand side, "flips" are coin flipping outcomes read from a file, while "rep" and "prior" are two parameters whose values I am trying to find. The function outputs randomness evaluation for all coin flips, which is a column vector with 256 elements.

```
csvread('judgement.csv')
```

Meanwhile, I had humans evaluate the same set of outcomes and their responses are stored in another column vector with 256 elements. (Note that humans judge how non-random instead of how random these outcomes are.)

I wish to minimize the correlation between two vectors.

```
corr(randomness, judgment)
```

On an abstract level, I guess the solution looks something like this:

```
function correlation = corr(randomness, judgment)
[...,fval] = fminsearch(@corr, ...)
```

However, the arguments are NOT directly the parameters ('rep' and 'prior') that I want to fit, but a function with them in it. I have no idea how to use fminsearch or other methods to find 'rep' and 'prior' when they are not explicitly in the arguments. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why something like `foo = @(X) corr(benHMMN(flips,X(1),X(2)),judgement)` and then `fminsearch(foo,[0 0])` wouldn't work

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this method, but MATLAB returns an error: fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:})

Comment: Please add the full output of the error. Also please check that the auxiliary function ‘foo ‘ returns only one scalar number

Comment: I closed all the windows and tried again. Then it worked! Sorry I do not have the full error message anymore. Thank you for your help again!